# Redux with socket.io

Tags: sockets, redux

Trying to modify [react-production-starter](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter) to use socket connection instead of rest.

What is the right way to deal with socket listeners? I've seen some open source projects where listeners were initiated right from containers (View) like regular Actions. That feels wrong.

So, i'm thinking how to do it better without breaking data prefetching on server-side rendering and avoid overcomplicating?

With this kit, may be I should put all listeners for each container into [Actions](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter/blob/master/common/routes/PostList/actions.js) wrapped in a single function, which will be called from [container](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-production-starter/blob/master/common/routes/PostList/index.js) and the Store will be passed as argument, so each incoming socket event will use `store.dispatch` function to dispatch regular Actions?
Outgoing socket events will be called from View the regular redux-way.